# How to remove website after cloning it with Tortoise hg?

Tags: tortoisehg

I have cloned a website using Tortoise hg but I need to remove it now since it's not being used. Any suggestions? With Tortoise Hg -> Remove files I get a lot of errors saying:

"not removing web\App_Data\TEMP\ClientDependency\1_ab4e3f1d41ae436d8fd9abaaa7f06b1e.cdJ: file is untracked"

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the directory for the repository.  The entire repository will be removed.

Comment: Odd to get a comment on this almost a year later :) When you say you need to remove the website what does that mean? `remove` command will remove individual files from being tracked in the repo the error message you get is likely because you are trying to remove files that are not part of the repo (i.e they have never been added